# How do I allow a function to be called with -erroraction

Tags: function, powershell, error-handling

I am writing a script that has `functionB` calling `functionA`. However I wish to error handle `functionA` from `functionB` by calling `functionA` and using the `-erroraction` flag, but my custom function can't be called with the `erroraction` flag

Example:

```
function functionA($var){
   #do something
}

function functionB($var1, $var2){
   try{
     $response = functionA $value -ErrorAction Stop
   }catch{
      #do something else
   }
}
```

how can I make something like this work?
error handling from `functionA` is not an option.

Comment: there's a global `$erroractionpreference`, you could set it to stop, before calling the function and revert it back after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute to enable that. Read more [about_Functions_CmdletBindingAttribute](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847872.aspx)

```
function functionA
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        $var
    )
   #do something
}

function functionB($var1, $var2){
   try{
     $response = functionA $value -ErrorAction
   }catch{
      #do something else
   }
}
```

---

**Note:** In PowerShell you should name your functions using the *Verb-Noun* convention. Also you should define your parameters in a `Param()` block. Curly brackets usually goes to a new line. So your functions could look like this:

```
function Test-FunctionA
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        $var
    )

   #do something
}

function Test-FunctionB
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        $var1,
        $var2
    )

   try
   {
     $response = Test-FunctionA $value -ErrorAction Stop
   }
   catch
   {
      #do something else
   }
}
```